# BeautifulSoup does not parse xml with other encoding than utf-8

Tags: xml, python-3.x, encoding, beautifulsoup

I can read all xmls files that starts with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` but I can not read the files starts with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`.

Specifically, I have two files:

**xml_iso.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
</note>
```

**xml-utf.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
</note>
```

With the following code I can find the `note` for the file with `utf-8` but I can not find it in the file with the other encoding. How can I solve that?

Example code:

```
import unittest

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

class TestEncoding(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_iso(self):
        with open('tests/xml-iso.xml', 'r') as f_in:
            xml_soup = Soup(f_in.read(), 'xml')
        print('xml-iso:\n{}'.format(xml_soup))
        note = xml_soup.find('note')
        self.assertIsNotNone(note)

    def test_utf8(self):
        with open('tests/xml-utf.xml', 'r') as f_in:
            xml_soup = Soup(f_in.read(), 'xml')
        print('xml-utf8:\n{}'.format(xml_soup))
        note = xml_soup.find('note')
        self.assertIsNotNone(note)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Versions:

- Python 3.5.2
- beautifulsoup4==4.6.0

Comment: It seems that `xml` can't handle iso. Not sure if it helps, but you can parse the document with `html.parser`.

Comment: Yes this is doable. But I have a lot of xmls and some of them are really big. The `html.parser` will be slower and the last solution if anything else does not work.

Comment: Finally, my workaround to this was that I changed with regex the encoding to `utf-8` to all xml files.

Answer (score 5):

Coincidentally I stumbled upon another workaround. Read the file in binary mode (`'rb'`):

```
with open('tests/xml-iso.xml', 'rb') as f_in:
    xml_soup = Soup(f_in.read(), 'xml')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem. My workaround is to not read the xml declaration:

```
with open('tests/xml-iso.xml', 'r', encoding='iso-8859-1') as f_in:
    f_in.readline()  # skipping header and letting soup create its own header
    xml_soup = Soup(f_in.read(), 'xml', from_encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```