# Cannot parse ISO-8859-15 encoded XML with bs4

Tags: xml, beautifulsoup, character-encoding

I have the following XML document, saved with Notepad++ in ISO-8859-15 encoding:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<someTag>
</someTag>
```

I try to parse this file using bs4, but somehow (even when specifying the encoding everywhere I can think of), I get an empty result:

```py
filepath = 'iso-8859-15_example.xml'
with open(filepath, encoding="iso-8859-15") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'xml', from_encoding="iso-8859-15")
print(soup)
# --> "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>", otherwise empty
```

Removing the encoding hints in the Python code does not help. But strangely, what works is deleting the first line of the XML file, which is the `<?xml ... ?>` statement (called "prolog, I think).

What am I doing wrong here? I thought the prolog would help bs4 to "do the right thing" and choose the correct encoding. Is there an alternative to deleting the prolog/messing with the XML-file encoding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup does not parse xml with other encoding than utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48203697/beautifulsoup-does-not-parse-xml-with-other-encoding-than-utf-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining Andrej's answer and the answers given in [the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48203697/beautifulsoup-does-not-parse-xml-with-other-encoding-than-utf-8), I can see that specifying raw mode in the `open` call solves my problem:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.diagnose import diagnose
with open('iso-8859-15_example.xml', 'rb') as f:
    diagnose(f)
```

This leads to the output

```
Diagnostic running on Beautiful Soup 4.7.1
Python version 3.6.7 (v3.6.7:6ec5cf24b7, Oct 20 2018, 13:35:33) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
I noticed that html5lib is not installed. Installing it may help.
Found lxml version 4.3.4.0
Trying to parse your markup with html.parser
Here's what html.parser did with the markup:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<sometag>
</sometag>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trying to parse your markup with lxml
Here's what lxml did with the markup:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<html>
 <body>
  <sometag>
  </sometag>
 </body>
</html>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trying to parse your markup with lxml-xml
Here's what lxml-xml did with the markup:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<someTag>
</someTag>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and shows that lxml in xml mode works well.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would recommend to run BeautifulSoup's `diagnose()` function:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from bs4.diagnose import diagnose

with open('iso-8859-15_example.xml', encoding="iso-8859-15") as f:
    diagnose(f.read())
```

On my machine this prints:

```
Diagnostic running on Beautiful Soup 4.7.1
Python version 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]]
Found lxml version 4.3.3.0
Found html5lib version 1.0.1

Trying to parse your markup with html.parser
Here's what html.parser did with the markup:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<sometag>
</sometag>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trying to parse your markup with html5lib
Here's what html5lib did with the markup:
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?-->
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <sometag>
  </sometag>
 </body>
</html>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trying to parse your markup with lxml
Here's what lxml did with the markup:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<html>
 <body>
  <sometag>
  </sometag>
 </body>
</html>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Trying to parse your markup with lxml-xml
Here's what lxml-xml did with the markup:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In this case, I would choose the `html.parser`, as It will do the right thing.

So when you do:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

It prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<sometag>
</sometag>
```

Comment: I want to parse it as xml, though (I have namespaces in my real file). I think it might work when specifying `open(filename, 'rb')`

Comment: @MartinJ.H. Namespace shouldn't be a problem, but you can try run `diagnose()` through some snippets of your code and see how different parsers will parse it.